# On Ubuntu the Apache DAV_SVN logs miss get/post method

Tags: apache, ubuntu, svn, webdav

On my server, ubuntu14.04, I installed the apache and libapache2-svn from apt-get, I found that the GET or POST method never be logged, What’s wrong with it? I need your help, thakns!

this is my dav_svn.conf:

```
<Location /project>
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /project
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/dav_svn.passwd
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/subversion/dav_svn.authz
    Require valid-user
    SVNIndexXSLT /svnstyle/svnindex.xsl
</Location>
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/svn/access.log "%m %I %O " env=SVN-ACTION
```

The "%m" 's values can be found are "PROPFIND", "REPORT", "MERGE", ..., except "GET", "POST".